# Web.config File Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-hosting, web-deployment

I am hosting a site through godaddy.com and this is the link:

http://floridaroadrunners.com/

and this is my web.config file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

<customErrors mode="Off"/>

    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I am getting runtime error:

> Runtime Error
>
> Description: An application error
>   occurred on the server. The current
>   custom error settings for this
>   application prevent the details of the
>   application error from being viewed
>   remotely (for security reasons). It
>   could, however, be viewed by browsers
>   running on the local server machine.

I have also set the customErrors mode = "off". What is wrong here? I am using Visual Studio 2010 with 4.0 framework in it. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the customErrors off is committed on the server?  You should be seeing the error if the mode is really off.

Comment: When this situation occurs to me, it's always been due to an error in the web.config format itself such that the config could not be parsed. What you posted looks OK, so I don't know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server's `machine.config` or `applicationHost.config` is likely overriding your `web.config` settings. Unfortunately there's nothing you can really do if that's the case, short of contacting GoDaddy's support line.

Comment: That's true, but it would seem strange for a shared hosting scenario to lock down that particular config setting.

Comment: That sounds a bit draconian, from them. I don't use them for Hosting, so I can't confirm or deny that.

Comment: I don't use them currently nor have I ever used them; I'm simply coming to the conclusion that makes the most sense without really speculating about their policies.

Answer (score 2):

If your host has enabled `customErrors`, you might consider catching and logging the exception yourself so you can see what's going on.

There are a couple options.  First, try [Elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/)

Second, you could use your logging library (I like NLog, but any will work), and catch the Application_Error event in Global.asax.cs.

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //first, find the exception.  any exceptions caught here will be wrapped
            //by an httpunhandledexception, which doesn't realy help us, so we'll
            //try to get the inner exception
            Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
            if (exception.GetType() == typeof(HttpUnhandledException) && exception.InnerException != null)
            {
                exception = exception.InnerException;
            }

            //get a logger from the container
            ILogger logger = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ILogger>();
            //log it
            logger.FatalException("Global Exception", exception);
        }
```

This is a good feature to have no matter what, even if you're able to get customErrors turned off.

Comment: Good suggestion to use Elmah! Just nuget install elmah.

Answer (score 0):

[customErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx) `mode` value `Off` is case sensitive I think. Please check that you have the first character capitalized.

Comment: I saw that too, but it looks like what OP has in the posted xml is correctly cased (what's posted later in the question isn't)

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the error in you Global.asax and sending an email with the exception.

In Global.asax.cs:

```
 void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
            Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
            ExceptionHandler.SendExceptionEmail(ex, "Unhandled", this.User.Identity.Name, this.Request.RawUrl);
            Response.Redirect("~/ErrorPage.aspx"); // So the user does not see the ASP.net Error Message
        }
```

My method in My ExceptionHandler Class:

```
class ExceptionHandler
    {
        public static void SendExceptionEmail(Exception ex, string ErrorLocation, string UserName, string url)
        {
            SmtpClient mailclient = new SmtpClient();
            try
            {
                string errorMessage = string.Format("User: {0}\r\nURL: {1}\r\n=====================\r\n{2}", UserName, url, AddExceptionText(ex));
                mailclient.Send(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ErrorFromEmailAddress"],
                                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ErrorEmailAddress"],
                                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ErrorEmailSubject"] + " = " + ErrorLocation,
                                errorMessage);
            }
            catch { }
            finally { mailclient.Dispose(); }
        }

        private static string AddExceptionText(Exception ex)
        {
            string innermessage = string.Empty;
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                innermessage = string.Format("=======InnerException====== \r\n{0}", ExceptionHandler.AddExceptionText(ex.InnerException));
            }
            string message = string.Format("Message: {0}\r\nSource: {1}\r\nStack:\r\n{2}\r\n\r\n{3}", ex.Message, ex.Source, ex.StackTrace, innermessage);
            return message;
        }
    }
```